# Perform action upon workbook being reactivated

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I've got a workbook which has buttons which open other workbooks through VBA.

My understanding is that this initial workbook (lets call it the Hub workbook), is both ThisWorkbook and ActiveWorkbook when I'm in it.

Upon opening another workbook through one of the buttons, the newly opened workbook becomes ActiveWorkbook.

When I click back on to Hub, it becomes ActiveWorkbook once again.

I'd like to perform an action, only when Hub regains the status of being the active workbook.

I've tried doing this by performing an action on the worksheet, but this doesn't perform if it's the only sheet and I just click back on it from another workbook.  It does if I have two worksheets for example and click back to this worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 MsgBox "Worksheet Reactivated"
End Sub
```

I can't seem to get it working as I require, but I'm sure there must be some way of doing this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you possibly looking for the [Workbook Activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.activate(even)) event?

Comment: I'd seen that and I don't think it's what I need.  That is telling the workbook to become active.  What I want is to do something once the active state is attained.  This state would be attained by the user actively clicking in this workbook.

Comment: @Satkin2 That is not what it is, that is an *event*, which occurs whenever the workbook becomes active.

Comment: There's a difference between `Workbook.Activate` and the event mentioned. The *event* "occurs when a workbook, worksheet, chart sheet, or embedded chart is activated."

Comment: I see I misunderstood it.  Using the answer below has sorted it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `Worksheet` module such as, say, `Sheet1`, is a special type of class module that inherits members of the `Worksheet` class, and lets you readily handle events defined for a `Worksheet` object. At run-time, that `Sheet1` module represents a very specific *instance* of the `Worksheet` class - so any event handlers you implement in that module, are only ever invoked for events fired from *that* object.

Thus, a `Worksheet_Activate` handler in the code-behind of `Sheet1` will only ever run when the `Sheet1` object fires its `Activate` event.

If you don't care for any specific or particular worksheet, then you need to handle events at a different level: the `ThisWorkbook` module is a special type of class module that inherits the members of the `Workbook` class, and lets you readily handle events defined for a `Workbook` object. This workbook object always represents *the specific workbook that hosts the VBA project you're in*, and no other workbook.

A `Workbook` object fires a `SheetActivate` event whenever *any sheet* (be it a `Worksheet`, a `Chart` sheet, or any other type of sheet) is activated - you get the activated sheet through the `Sh` parameter of the corresponding handler.

A `Workbook` object also fires its own `Activate` event whenever it becomes the `ActiveWorkbook`.

Looks like you want to handle a `Workbook` event. Experiment with the handlers you can get in the `ThisWorkbook` module, see what best fits your requirements.

Select `Workbook` from the combobox at the top-left of the code pane in `ThisWorkbook`, then select an event from the right-hand side combobox, to get the VBE to automatically generate an event handler prototype with the correct signature:

[image: ThisWorkbook code pane dropdowns]

If you need to handle `Application`-wide events, things get a little bit more involved, but the crux of it is that you need to have a class module (could be `ThisWorkbook`) that declares a `WithEvents` variable:

```
Private WithEvents App As Excel.Application
```

And now the top-left dropdown will list `App`, and when that's selected the top-right dropdown will let you pick an `Excel.Application` event to handle... provided that you `Set` this `App` object variable to a valid `Excel.Application` reference, say, in the `Workbook_Open` handler:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Me.Application
End Sub
```

Now you can handle an event that's fired when *any* workbook is activated, for example.

Comment: Perfect, I wasn't aware of this.  Thank you.